# My browser extension modifies the DOM. How do I stop this from interfering with page scripts?

Tags: web-development, browser, plugins

I'm writing a WebExtensions browser plugin that will modify the DOM of the current page when the user presses a button in the toolbar. More specifically, I need to insert HTML tags into the DOM. Even more specifically, every word on the page needs to be wrapped in a span tag.

In principle there's no way to predict how this might intefere with page scripts. For example, if a page has a script that relies on the number of span tags in the page being 25, and then my script adds 800 new ones, I'll break the page script.

How can I get around this issue? I've thought of a few alternatives:

1. "Freeze" the page. When the user pushes a button to activate the extension, the page essentially becomes static HTML. My extension won't allow any DOM changes from page scripts after it runs.
2. Clone the DOM and overlay the cloned DOM over the old page using z-levels. Insert my HTML into the clone and let page scripts act on the original copy. Monitor the original page for DOM changes and mimic them in my clone.
3. Screw it. The extension won't work on pages with scripts that rely on the DOM not having the extra span elements in it. Do testing to make sure that doesn't happen on popular websites.

Modifying the page DOM isn't exactly obscure behavior for extension. What are the general strategies for avoiding disastrous conflicts?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a browser extension I would ever want to install.  What does it do, exactly?  Does the plugin's benefits exceed its apparent intrusiveness?

Comment: See also [What is the X Y Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Skype used to do this with phone numbers, which broke certain windows in Dynamics CRM. Naturally, our CRM was more important that auto linking phone numbers... So we removed Skype plugins. ... Had Skype made this more configurable (for novice users), we could have and *would* have left it installed... It was definitely useful for our sales reps *most* of the time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey A translation plugin for use as a language-learning aid. Wrapping each word in a span tag is the only way to get the required behavior. The extension is turned on and off with a button, it is not on at all times. It seems to me that this isn't necessarily relevant since many extensions modify the DOM and you have to worry about possible conflicts the moment you modify it at all, not just if you modify it a lot.

Comment: What is the behavior you're getting from span wrappers that you can't get otherwise?

Comment: "many extensions modify the DOM" - I don't think many extensions modify the DOM with the expectation to work flawlessly with any website. For example, Greasemonkey scripts are typically written for specific sites or categories of sites, or they don't make such intrusive changes, or they fight against the same problems like your extension. For your use case, I think Option 2 sounds like the best solution (or Option 1, together with a possibility of letting the user easily go back to the original page and unfreeze it).

Comment: @ErikEidt I need a little colored rectangle around each word, I need a popup translation when you mouseover it, and I need to add context menu items when you right click on a word.

Comment: Instead of wrapping the whole page. Why don't you just allow user to select the word(s) to translate? And add the contextual menu only to the selected elements.

Comment: Why would freezing the page somehow be better than potentially breaking the script? A broken script stops executing, and your solution is to stop script execution altogether. How does that avoid the problem situation that sparked this question?

Answer (score -1):

> every word on the page needs to be wrapped in a span tag.

Insert the new DOM as an `object` tag. For example:

```
var dom = new DOMParser();

var obj = document.createElement("object");

var foo = document.body.innerText.replace(/\s/g, "<span>");

var bar = dom.parseFromString(foo, "text/html");

console.log(bar);

obj.setAttribute("data", "data:text/html;charset=utf-8;," + foo);

document.body.appendChild(obj);
```

**References**

- [RFC 2397 - The "data" URL scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397)
- [DOM Parsing and Serialization](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/)
- [object data-uri](https://jsfiddle.net/twophayse/j15b1dpz/)